# $L_p([a,b])$ is the completion of $C[a,b]$: reference

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, normed-spaces

Let $p\geq1$ be a real number and $L_p([a,b])=L_p([a,b],\mathcal{B}, \lambda)$ be the normed space which consists of all equivalence classes of $\mathcal{B}$-measurable functions $f$ on $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb R$ such that $\int_{[a,b]}|f|^p d\lambda<\infty$. Here,

- $\mathcal B$ is the Borel algebra,
- $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure,
- $f\sim g \Leftrightarrow f=g$ a.e. and
- the norm $||\cdot||_p$ is given by $$||f||_p=\left(\int_{[a,b]}|f|^p d\lambda\right)^{1/p}.$$

Moreover, let $C[a,b]$ be the set of continuous functions on $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb R$. Then, make $M:=\left\{\overline{f}:f\in C[a,b]\right\}$. I'd like to show that the completion of the normed space $(M, ||\cdot||_p)$ is $(L_p([a,b]),||\cdot||_p)$. I guess all I need to do is to prove that $M$ is dense in $(L_p([a,b])$.

I could find the proof of more general statements, for example, in Reddy's *Introductory Functional Analysis* or in Nair's *Functional Analysis: a first course*. But, for simplicity, I'd like to discover a reference with deals specifically with this particular case. Could someone indicate a book with this proof? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the definition of $\bar f$ ?

Comment: @Youem, $\overline{f}$ is the class of $f$ under the equivalence relation $\sim$: $\overline{f}=\{g:g\sim f\}$.

Comment: How about $M \subset L^p$ and every element of $L^p$ is a limit of a sequence of $M$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** Proving that $L_p([a,b])$ is the completion of $M$ is to show that there is a subspace $W$ of $L_p([a,b])$ such that $W$ is dense in $L_p([a,b])$ and $W$ is isometric with $M$ in the sense that there is a bijective isometry from $M$ to $W$. Since any inclusion is a bijective isometry, it's suffices to verify that $M$ is dense in $L_p([a,b])$. This verification can be found on [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226049/continuous-functions-on-0-1-is-dense-in-lp0-1-for-1-leq-p-infty/2691177#2691177/%20this%20post). There, were used Lusin's theorem, Tietze extension theorem and a proposition of Royden and Fitzpatrick's  *Real Analysis*.