# Density of $C[0,1]$ in $L^p[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

The density of $C[0,1]$ in $L^p[0,1]$ is shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/226100/818765) by showing we can approximate characteristic functions in the uniform norm (and consequently $L^p$ norm) by a continuous function, i.e. we want to show that

$$\forall\varepsilon>0\quad\forall E\in\mathfrak{M}([0,1])\quad\exists f\in C([0,1])\quad
\Vert f-\chi_E\Vert<\varepsilon
$$
The answer proceeds by using the regularity of the Lebesgue measure to find a closed set $F$ and  an open set $U$ such that,
$F\subset E\subset U$ with $\mu(U\setminus F)<\varepsilon$ and claiming that the desired $f\in C([0,1])$ is
$$
f(t)=\frac{d(t, [0,1]\setminus U)}{d(t, [0,1]\setminus U)+d(t,F)}
$$
where $d(t, S)=\inf\{|t-s|:s\in S\}$ is the distance function.

I am trying to show that such an $f$ indeed works.

First of all, when $t \in F$ or $t \in [0,1]\setminus U$, we have $f(t)=\chi_E(t)$.

Thus, $f$ and $\chi_E$ only differ on $U\setminus F$. But how do I show their difference is at most $\epsilon$ there?

Edit: We are approximating in the $L^p$ norm, not the sup norm. The conclusion follows immediately now by observing $f$ and $\chi_E$ differ only on $U\setminus F$ which has measure at most $\epsilon$.

Comment: You can't really approximate a characteristic function by any continuous function with respect to the uniform norm (if by uniform norm you mean the sup norm).

Comment: @ArcticChar Oh, I just realized this is wrong. We can approximate in the $L^p$ norm, not the sup norm. The former is immediate by noting that $\mu(U\setminus F)<\epsilon$.